# Add Button programmatically with parameters?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button

Basically, I have this layout structure: `<RelativeLayout> <RelativeLayout> <TextView /> </RelativeLayout> <ScrollView> <RelativeLayout> ... </RelativeLayout> </ScrollView> </RelativeLayout>` and I want to add a button programmatically. This button should be inside the `<RelativeLayout>`, which is inside the `<ScrollView>`. Also, I need it to be align to the bottom and CENTER_VERTICAL. 
I would really appreciate any hints/examples ;) Thanks!
P.S. Although, there are many similar questions on stackoverflow, none of the answers helped me...

Comment: select xml and press CTRL+SHIFT+K to format the code so that it will be looks good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to give your relative Layout in XML an ID: `android:id="@+id/myLayout"`.
Then in Java code:

```
Button b = new Button(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
b.setLayoutParams(rl);
((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout)).addView(b);
```

Comment: Thank You so much! I also added `params.bottomMargin = 20;` for a nicer look and change my .xml file, because the RelativeLayout there had 'WRAP_CONTENT' and it was impossible to align my button to the bottom.

Comment: I was also interested if I can "say" programmatically, that the newly created button should be below some `TextView`, for instance? Thanks.

Comment: Sure you can: `rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.textview01);`

Comment: buttons are getting on top of each other, how to make them go right side and if space is full then below. Please help.