# Ecplise - Android Add a button with code

Tags: android, button

I´m trying to add a button to my screen but I can´t seem to get it to work.
This is my code:

```
    public class Graph extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle values = getIntent().getExtras();
    float value1 = values.getFloat("value1");
    float value2 = values.getFloat("value2");
    float value3 = values.getFloat("value3");
    float value4 = values.getFloat("value4");
    float value5 = values.getFloat("value5");
    System.out.println(values);
    setContentView(new GraphView(this, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5));
    // I guess it´s here I add my button?
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_graph, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

I do not know how I can add a button because I use this code

```
     setContentView(new GraphView(this, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5));
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Button b = new Button(this); add the button to your layout.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Button programmatically with parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698650/add-button-programmatically-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to define where you want to add your button. If you want to add it bellow your GraphView then do it like this

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.addView(new GraphView(this, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5);
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("Button text");
ll.addView(button);
setContentView(ll);
```

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: I do not get any error, but I can´t see my button, is there any way to say where it should appear?

Comment: If I remove the line "ll.addView(new GraphView(this, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5);"
I can see the button -_-
So I guess I have to change something on GraphView so it do not take up all space on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
    Button myButton = new Button(yourActivity.this);
myButton.setText("Click");

RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourlayout);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ll.addView(myButton, lp);
```

Comment: Before I got error at "new Button(this)" but it seems to work now. But the new problem now is that I can´t find any layout in "R.Id.layout"

Comment: that layout is your parent layout id.Check your main xml layout file to get the id of parent layout(It will be a Relative layout or Linear layout).

Comment: It´s a RelativeLayout, but I can´t seem to find any ID

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

Comment: add  android:id="@+id/yourlayout" to your layout. And see my edited answer for relative layout